# Android phone will not show all WiFi access points

Tags: wi-fi, 4.1-jelly-bean

I have a [LG-D686](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_g_pro_lite_dual-5736.php) running its stock factory installation of Android 4.1.2 Jelly Bean; modified somewhat by the vendor to support a dual-active SIM card transceiver. Normally this phone has had no difficulties finding and connecting to WiFi Access Points.

However, I now work in an office *whose WiFi Access Point is not showing on my Andoid phone*.

This is what I know:

- The office WAP is not an ad-hoc wifi hotspot. It is an always-on [Linksys LAPAC1750 Pro](http://www.linksys.com/en-us/business/products/accesspoints/lapac1750).
- The office WAP is visible from my Windows 7 work laptop and from other colleagues' iPhones. I've not checked if anyone has an Android Jelly Bean phone in the office.
- My Android shows up most but not all access points in the building. There are approximately 15 - 20 access points visible from my Windows laptop using Xirrus Wi-Fi Inspector; depending on the time of week. Android Wifi Analyzer shows that as much 80% of laptop-visible WAPs are visible on my phone.
- The office WAP has a decent signal; more than most WAPs that are showing up.
- If I create a non-ad-hoc wifi hotspot on my laptop (using Connectify); this hotspot will be visible if the laptop is not in the office and invisible if the laptop is in the office!
- No obvious and evident differences between visible and invisible WAPs other than the office access point is the only one in this building using channel 12.

**What might I do to resolve this WAP visibility problem?**